# Почему не удаляется строка в PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Хочу удалить строку в PhpMyAdmin. Жму на крестик у ненужной мне строки, подтверждаю popup и меня перекидывает на вкладку "Вставка". Открываю снова вкладку "Обзор" - строка на месте. Прикладываю скриншоты. Пробовал перезапускать сервер, пробовал делать это в других браузерах - то же самое.
[image: изображение 1][image: изображение2][image: изображение 3]

Comment: Не сталкивался с таким. Не висит ли какой-нибудь триггер на удаление данных из таблицы? Второе - что будет, если выполните запрос указанный в попап'е на вкладке 'SQL'?

Answer (score 0):

Удали вручную скорее всего поможет. Заходишь в базу данных свою -> SQL и пишешь запрос. DELETE FROM users WHERE id='61'; Но!! Перед тем как писать смотришь в правый верхний угол и там значок шестеренки туда тыкаешь и убираешь галочку с "Подтверждать DROP запросы" сохраняешь и только тогда пиши запрос.[image: phpmyadmin]